# asp.net enviar un pdf adjunto a un email

Tags: asp.net, pdf, email

Me han pedido adjuntar un pdf de una vista en asp.net en un email, lo cual he resuelto, el problema es que cuando se envia, el email el archivo adjunto solo tiene html, nada de jquery ni bootstrap, nada. Creo que es por la solucion a la que he llegado la cual es en la vista create al hacer click en el boton create procesar la informacion y luego de salvar la informacion en la base de datos es que procede a generar el pdf y luego enviar el email.

Estoy usando Rotativa para crear un pdf desde una vista.

Intente crear un partitial View, el problema que al querer guardar el formulario, crear el pdf y enviar el email, todo con un solo boton el partitial view que se crear es para informacion que ya existe y esta aun esta por crear y me da error

aqui es el actionResult create:

```
   public ActionResult Create(factura factura)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session["Id"] != null && Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Admin") || Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Camionero"))
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string pic = string.Empty;
                    string folder = "~/Content/imagenes";
                    string folderFirma = "~/Content/firmas";


                    Image firma = Upload(factura.firma);

                    factura.firmaImage = firma;


                    string firmaImageName = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm") + ".jpg";
                    string ruta2 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(folderFirma), firmaImageName);

                    factura.firmaImage.Save(ruta2);

                    if (factura.lecturaFinal != null)
                    {
                        decimal? remanente = factura.lecturaInicial - factura.lecturaFinal;

                        db.camion.Find(1).remanente = remanente;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        decimal? remanente = db.camion.Find(1).remanente;

                        db.camion.Find(1).remanente = remanente - factura.galones;
                    }




                    //factura.firma = "~/Content/firmas/hello2.jpg";
                    factura.firma = string.Format("{0}/{1}", folderFirma, firmaImageName);

                    //  siguiendo la ruta

                    pic = Path.GetFileName(factura.imageFile.FileName);

                    string ruta = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(folder), pic);

                    factura.imageFile.SaveAs(ruta);


                    pic = string.Format("{0}/{1}", folder, pic);

                    factura.horaSalida = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();


                    factura.foto = pic;


                    db.factura.Add(factura);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                   //aqui se salva la informacion a la base de datos y luego procedo con la logica de crear el pdf y luego enviar el email

                    var pdf = new ViewAsPdf2("pdf", factura);
                    byte[] pdfByteArray = pdf.GetByte(ControllerContext);

                    string from = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmailID"];
                    string to = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToEmailID"];
                    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
                    message.Subject = "test";
                    message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    message.Body = "Esto es un test de generacion del pdf y el envio de un archivio adjunto en el email";
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream(pdfByteArray);
                    file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    Attachment data = new Attachment(file, "RunTime_Attachment.pdf", "application/pdf");
                    ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition; //mime o rotativa
                    disposition.CreationDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                    disposition.ModificationDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                    disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
                    message.Attachments.Add(data);

                    SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTP"]);
                    SmtpMail.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]);
                    SmtpMail.Port = 587;
                    SmtpMail.EnableSsl = true;
                    SmtpMail.Send(message);




                    return RedirectToAction("Index");

                }

                ViewBag.fichaCamion = new SelectList(db.camion, "id", "camion1", factura.fichaCamion);
                ViewBag.cliente = new SelectList(db.cliente, "id", "compania", factura.cliente1);
                return View(factura);

            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

            //return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            //throw;
        }
    }
```

aqui esta la vista del pdf

```
@model Prueba_concepto.factura

 @{
ViewBag.Title = "PDF_details";

}


<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

 @section Styles {
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Styles/nav-bar.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 }
 @*@RenderSection("Content/css", false)*@

<html>
<head>
<script>
    //window.onload = function () {
    //    var refTab = document.getElementById("tabla")
    //    var ttl;
    //     Loop through all rows and columns of the table and popup alert with the value
    //     /content of each cell.
    //    for (var i = 0; row = refTab.rows[i]; i++) {
    //        row = refTab.rows[i];
    //        for (var j = 0; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
    //            alert(col.firstChild.nodeValue);

    //            if (row.cells[3] == null) {
    //                alert("esta nulo el chamo");
    //            }
    //        }
    //    }
    //}

    window.onload = function () {
        var a = $("#lectura").text();
        if (a != "") {

            $('#tabla2').css("display", "none");
            //$("#inicial").css("display", "initial");
            //$("#final").css("display", "initial");
            //var inicial = $("#lectura").text();
            //alert("si tengo algo");
            //alert("tengo alguito");
        } else {

            $("#tabla3").css("display", "none");
            // $("#final").css("display", "none");
            // alert("no tengo na");


        }

        var codigo = $("#codigo").text();
       // var codigo = '0096';
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Facturas/buscarCodigoPdf?codigo=' + codigo,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == "ok") {

                    $("#cliente").text(data.name);
                    $("#rnc").text(data.rnc);
                    $("#direccion").text(data.direccion);
                    $("#tel").text(data.phone);
                } else {
                    alert("paso algo raro");
                }
            }
        })

    }

    //$(document).ready(function () {
    //    var codigo = $("#codigo").text();
    //    $.ajax({
    //        url: '/Facturas/buscarCodigoPdf?nombre=' + codigo,
    //        success: function (data) {
    //            if (data.status == "ok") {

    //                $("#cliente").text(data.name);
    //                $("#rnc").text(data.rnc);
    //                $("#direccion").text(data.direccion);
    //                $("#tel").text(data.phone);
    //            } else {
    //                alert("paso algo raro");
    //            }
    //        }
    //    })
    //})

    //$(document).ready(function () {
    //    $("#btn2").click(function () {
    //        var nombre = $("#codigoCompany").val();
    //        $.ajax({
    //            url: '/Facturas/buscarCodigoPdf?nombre=' + nombre,
    //            success: function (data) {
    //                if (data.status == "ok") {


    //                } else {
    //                    alert("paso algo raro");
    //                }
    //            }
    //        })
    //    })
    //})



</script>
```

```
<hr />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-xs-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 " style="margin-top:35px;">
            <center>
                <img src="~/Content/imagenes/codigo de barra.jpg" width="300" height="60" />
            </center>
            <h5 class="text-center"><strong>CONDUCE / VALIDACION DE ENTREGA</strong></h5>


        </div>

    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-6">

                @*<legend class="scheduler-border">Cliente</legend>*@
                <p>
                    <b>Codigo</b> : <span id="codigo">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.codigoCompany)</span> 
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Cliente</b> : <span id="cliente"></span>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <b>RNC</b> : <span id="rnc"></span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Direccion</b> : <span id="direccion"></span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Telefono</b> : <span id="tel"></span>
                </p>



            <table class="table table-bordered" style="table-layout:auto" id="tabla2">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" class="text-center colorFondo">
                            Sellos Superioes
                        </th>
                        <th colspan="2" class="text-center colorFondo">
                            Sellos Inferiores
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="10" class="colorFondo">
                            <b>1</b>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.selloDescarga1)
                        </td>
                        <td width="10" class="colorFondo">
                            <b>1</b>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.selloManhole1)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="colorFondo">
                            <b>2</b>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.selloDescarga2)
                        </td>
                        <td class="colorFondo">
                            <b>2</b>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.selloManhole2)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="colorFondo">
                            <b>3</b>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.selloDescarga3)
                        </td>
                        <td class="colorFondo">
                            <b>3</b>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.selloManhole3)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>



                <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabla3">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Totalizador</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="200" class="colorFondo text-center"><b>Lectura Inicial</b></td>
                            <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.lecturaInicial)</td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="colorFondo text-center"><b>Lectura Final</b></td>
                            <td id="lectura" class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.lecturaFinal)</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">

                <p>
                    <b>No. DE CONDUCE</b> : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.id)
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Fecha</b> : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.fecha)
                </p>

                <p>
                    <b>No de Orden</b> : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.horaEntrada)
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Unidad</b> : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.camion.camion1)
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Capacidad</b> : 3,000
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Chofer</b> : Sr. @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.camion.nombre)
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Hora Entrada</b> : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.horaEntrada)
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Hora Salida</b> : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.horaSalida)
                </p>

        </div>

    </div>



    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            @*<p>
                    <b>Entregado por</b> :  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.camion.nombre)
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Unidad</b> : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.camion.camion1)
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Imagen producto recibido</b> :  <img src="@Url.Content(Model.foto)" alt="Image" style="width:100px;height:180px;" />
                </p>*@

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p>

                </p>
                <p>

                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table class="table text-center" id="tabla">
            <thead class="text-center">
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Codigo Producto
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Descripción Producto
                    </th>
                    <th class="text-center">
                        Galones Totales
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.codigo)</td>
                    <td>La descripcion aqui</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.galones)</td>


                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p>
                    <b>Recibido Por</b> :
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Nombre</b> :
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Cedula</b> :
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Firma</b> :
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <p class="text-center">
                            <b>Imagen Producto Recibido Y Verificado De Impurezas</b>
                        </p>
                        <center>
                            <img src="@Url.Content(Model.foto)" width="100" height="150" />
                        </center>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />



        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h5 class="text-center">

                </h5>
                <h6 style="text-align:justify">
                    •   
                </h6>
                <h6 style="text-align:justify">
                    •   
                </h6>
                <h6 style="text-align:justify">
                    •   
                </h6>
                <h6 style="text-align:justify">
                    •   
                </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 pd">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias por las sugerencias

He resuelto la mayoria de los problemas que tenia.

Estoy usando asp.net mvc razor y le agregue en la vista el diseño normal de una web html

```
<head>
aqui escribi los scripts de bootstrap y jquery

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Styles/nav-bar.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Es decir, ya la vista crea todos esos tags, pero no me funcionaban los stilos, css, bootstrap ni jquery y de esta forma me funcionan

Ahora el problema que tengo es que tengo una funcion que hace una llamada ajax a una base de datos y no me trae la informacion. Alguna idea del por que?

He resuelto esta situacion de esta manera, me fije que el pdf si tenia los propiedades del modelo, tons lo que hice fue agregar unas cuantas propiedades [noMapped] al modelo y agregarlas a la vista del pdf y en el controlador hacer la llamada del query.

Este es el codigo que agregue al controlador con las propiedades extras del modelo

```
cn.Open();
                        string query = string.Format("select name, billAddressAddr3, billAddressBlockAddr4, phone, email from customer where CompanyName = '{0}'", factura.codigoCompany);
                    OdbcCommand command;
                    OdbcDataReader reader;


                    using (command = new OdbcCommand(query, cn))
                    {

                        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        string name;
                        string rnc = string.Empty;
                        string direccion = string.Empty;
                        string phone = string.Empty;
                        string email = string.Empty;

                        if (reader.HasRows == true)
                        {
                            name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                            rnc = reader["BillAddressAddr3"].ToString();
                            direccion = reader["BillAddressBlockAddr4"].ToString();
                            phone = reader["Phone"].ToString();
                            email = reader["email"].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            name = "nombre del cliente no existe, no se mostrara los demas datos";

                        }

                        //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        // var clienteData = { name = name, rnc = rnc, direccion = direccion, phone = phone, email = email };
                        var data2 = new { status = "ok", name = name, rnc = rnc, direccion = direccion, phone = phone, email = email };
                        cn.Close();

                        factura.clienteNombre = data2.name;
                        factura.clienteRNC = data2.rnc;
                        factura.clienteDireccion = data2.direccion;
                        factura.clienteTelefono = data2.phone;
                        factura.clienteEmail = data2.email;

                    }
```

De esta forma puedo hacer exactamente lo mismo que con la llamada Ajax.

Muchas gracias por sus sugerencias

Comment: Buen dia, reformula tu pregunta si tienes dos problemas dos preguntas, y para cada pregunta solo agrega el codigo involucrado, para cada pregunta que error o duda especifica tienes.

Comment: Gracias por la observacion, creo que el problema esta en que rotativa no soporta llamadas ajax, a ver como hago eso desde el controller, si lo logro publico aqui la solucion